# In numpy, why is .var() a method while mean() is a normal function?

Tags: python, numpy, methods

As an R programmer learning Python, I've been getting confused by the Python syntax a few times. Many of these behaviors seem arbitrary to me. It would help me to understand the reasons behind why things are the way they are in Python. I'm also new to OOP, so this might be the reason for my confusion.

Specifically, these two points confused me the most while following a tutorial:

1. To compute an array's mean, you use `np.mean(myarray)`. But to compute the variance, you use `myarray.var()` (that's a *method*, right?). This seems arbitrary - was there a reason for choosing to implement things in this way?
2. Plotting a histogram consists of two subsequent commands, `plot.hist(values, 50)` followed by `plt.show()`. Why is the second call necessary? And where does the "result" of the first call get stored? Is this some kind of OOP magic?

Comment: Note that it's not really python syntax, but numpy/matplotlib specific syntax. Matplotlib `plot` commands are actually [made to look like matlab](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

Comment: many numpy functions (Including `mean` and `var`) support both function and method use. the advantage of the function variant is that it can be applied to array like objects like lists that do not have the method.

Comment: numpy, in my opinion, goes a bit against the "one obvious way to do it" philosophy of python. lots of things can be done either by methods or by a module level function. and in some cases, following no particular logic, there is only  a method or a module level function.

Comment: @Mel Thanks, that helps. I remember Matlab plots as having a very different syntax from R. Is there a way to use matplotlib in a different way? I'm asking because it seems that the Matlab syntax comes from the pyplot submodule.

Comment: @PaulPanzer What's the advantage of the method variant, then?

Comment: That's standard OOP I'd say, stuff that operates on the internals of a class instance should be dealt with by that class because it knows best and because that way you achieve modularity. If I'm not mistaken the function versions check whether the operand has a suitable method and call that if found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these methods both ways:  The reasoning was to make scientific python packages friendly for users not comfortable with OOP, and provide a familiar API to people used to matlab, or R.
As pointed out in the comments by @Mel, the matplotlib package also shares this feature.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([range(10)])
a.mean(), a.var(), np.mean(a), np.var(a)
```

#### output:

```
(4.5, 8.25, 4.5, 8.25)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! The course mentioned only the method way for the variance.

Comment: it is indeed sometimes quite confusing; in the particular case of python scientific tools, history explains the design decisions.

Comment: Another important reason why the function exists is that you can drop other iterables, like `list`s or `tuple`s, into `mean` and friends.